# github pages ruhoh theme not working

Tags: html, github, ruhoh

I'm using ruhoh (a static site generator) to set up a github pages site. Ruhoh has generated a index.html file associated with its default theme, but github is insisting that the file does not exist. You can see the code here: https://github.com/madCode/madcode.github.io/blob/master/index.html

and the url here: http://madcode.github.io/index.html

As you can see I'm getting a 404 file not found error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it has something to do with the generated html?

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong, you have an index.html in the master branch, which should work. As a wild guess, the case mismatch between your username (madCode) and your repository name (madcode.github.io) could be causing problems.

Comment: I hope that's not the problem! I can't make a repository with a capital letters in it. I know it's not a problem in general, when I wasn't using ruhoh (and just had a bunch of html files) my site worked perfectly. And the index file is there...

Comment: @KamalaPhoenix, *neither* of your links works for me. Are you 100% positive that the file exists?

Comment: I see that you have it working now. It would be great if you answer your own question with the solution, so that others with the same problem can learn from you!

Comment: Well, I ended up giving up and switching to jekyll since I couldn't get ruhoh working. I wasn't sure that counted as a solution so I didn't answer my own question.